# Issues with gitlab while using docker

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to install docker gitlab image in my ubuntu 18.04 while following the [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#after-starting-a-container), so that I can use gitlab locally.

for this I ran the command

```
sudo docker run --detach \
--hostname gitlab.labs.com \
--publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
--name gitlab-labs \
--restart unless-stopped \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

it first downloaded the image and then while starting it said the 443 is already in use. When I checked Ngnix is running on the port, so I have stopped that ngnix service. Later it gave me error 22 port is already inuse. so I killed the proccess on port 22 using kill command.

Finally I could make the docker running (checked --> docker ps)

Now I am trying to access http://gitlab.labs.com it says "Server Not Found".

when i checked the port connections

```
lsof -i:22
>COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 15736 root    4u  IPv4 148125      0t0  TCP ISL-D:ssh (LISTEN)
>lsof -i:443
docker-pr 15711 root    4u  IPv4 149948      0t0  TCP ISL-D:https (LISTEN)
>lsof -i:80    
docker-pr 15724 root    4u  IPv4 151075      0t0  TCP ISL-D:http (LISTEN)
```

even i tried with accessing my local ip 10.x.x.x the webpage says welcome to nginx.

any issue with the installation ? Or did I miss something ?

UPDATE:@Miq

After the changes things are like this

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.labs.com \
  --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://gitlab.labs.com/'; gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true;" \
  --publish 10.10.60.7:443:443\
  --publish 10.10.60.7:80:80\
  --publish 10.10.60.7:22:22\
  --name gitlab-labs \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Comment: Have yo set the external url in `gitlab.rb`?

Comment: When I have downloaded the docker file also, should I do that ? in command i gave as hostname, is it not the same ?

Comment: I see that as later steps, so I didnt go through, I will update and check !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `gitlab.rb` because nginx has baked in DNS reverse proxy and it routes internally based on this parameter. The `--hostname` is just for docker, nginx cannot read from it.

```
Once you open /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb make sure to set the external_url to point to a valid URL.
```

Comment: though i have edited 
sudo docker exec -it gitlab-labs editor /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb --> external_url "http://gitlab.labs.com" , its still the same.

any thing more to do ?

Comment: I have a web domain www.labs.com(just example) so for operating gitlab i want that as gitlab.labs.com, do we need to update any DNS in the site where I purchased the site ?

Comment: I have installed the docker image on system having 10.10.60.7 IP address.

Comment: The hostname you connect to needs to resolve to IP address you put in docker command.